# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, concatenação-de-string

Criei um exemplo fictício de um desconto no salário de uma pessoa, o código funciona, porém aparecem dois *notices* que listei abaixo do código:

```
    class Descontos{

        public $salario;
        public $inss;
        public $salarioLiquido;

        public function calcularPorcentagemINSS():float{
            if($this->salario < 1693.62 ){
                $this->inss = 8/100;
            } else if( $this->salario > 1693.63 OR $this->salario < 2822.90 ) {
                $this->inss = 9/100;
            } else {
                $this->inss = 11/100;
            }

            return $this->inss;
        }

        public function calcularValorINSS(){
            return $this->inss * $this->salario;
        }

        public function calcularSalarioLiquido(){
            return $this->salario - $this->calcularValorINSS();
        }

    }

    # INSTÂNCIA DA CLASSE
    $salario = new Descontos();

    echo "Salário bruto: " . $salario->salario = 2000 . "<br/>";

    echo "Porcentagem INSS: " . $salario->calcularPorcentagemINSS() * 100 . "% <br/>";

    echo "Valor de desconto INSS: " . $salario->calcularValorINSS() . "<br/>";

    echo "Salário Líquido: " . $salario->calcularSalarioLiquido();
```

Notices apresentados:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\18 - POO\06 - class.php on line 23
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\18 - POO\06 - class.php on line 27

Como posso resolvê-los?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando está fazendo

```
$salario->salario = 2000 . "<br/>"
```

está convertendo todo o valor em *string* e ele está sendo guardado na variável. Como há uma concatenação virará `"2000 <br/>"`, portanto não faz o que espera. Para resolver isto teria que fazer a atribuição em linha separada, como todo mundo faz, ou pelo menos usar parênteses no local adequado:

```
echo "Salário bruto: " . ($salario->salario = 2000) . "<br/>";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/AmbiguosConcat.php).

Além desse, há outros problemas técnicos, até mesmo na criação da classe. E há erros conceituais na utilização de orientação a objetos. E nem falei ainda da desnecessidade de uma classe para isso. Uma coisa que venho falando bastante e todos ignoram é que há muita preocupação em usar OOP, mas pouca em fazer código certo que é o que importa. E na maior parte do tempo código certo nada tem a ver com OOP, pelo contrário, é comum o código ser mais certo sem OOP. Orientação a objeto é difícil e até as pessoas experientes têm dificuldade de fazer certo. Por isso, se não tiver muita vantagem deveria evitar o seu uso, principalmente até dominar muito bem o paradigma (o que exige profundo estudo, e hoje em dia raro quem quer fazer isso, as pessoas estão só fingindo que fazem código certo, por isso quase tudo que você vê falha muito na web).

Comment: Obrigado pela solução apresentada e pelas dicas. Comecei a estudar Programação Orientada a Objetos hoje, em quais casos você me aconselharia utilizar esse estilo de programação?

Comment: Naqueles extramente complexos, ou seja, em PHP não faz sentido em quase todos os casos. Na verdade não sei se adianta muito eu dizer isso porque quase todo material que tem por aí ensina OOP errado.